# Tkinter performance degrades when I change PNG files but I can't figure out why

Tags: python, tkinter, photoshop, tkinter-canvas

I've been learning some basic python gui stuff for a project, I've created an animation for an RPM dial, when I use the first PNG exported from Photoshop, it works fine. However when I add more features to the dial in PS and then use that PNG exported with the same settings the performance degrades noticeably. The file sizes are the same on paper but clearly not in reality, I'm wondering if there's a workaround in the code or export.

The python script

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import CENTER
from PIL import ImageTk,Image  

# --- Main application set up ---
main_app = tk.Tk()
main_app.title('DT1')
width_value=main_app.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value=main_app.winfo_screenheight()

#width_value=1400
#height_value=1000
#main_app.geometry("%dx%d+0.5+0.5" % (width_value, height_value))
main_app.geometry("%dx%d" % (width_value, height_value))

# Frame setup
frame = tk.Frame(main_app, bg='black')
frame.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

# DES Logo
DES_logo=tk.Label(frame, text='DT1', font='ariel 18 bold', bg='#000000', fg='#626262')
DES_logo.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.91, relwidth=0.20, relheight=0.05)

#Canvas
my_canvas2 = tk.Canvas(frame, width = 800, height = 120, background = 'black', highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas2.place(x=10, y=10)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r'C:/Users/Sandip Dhillon/Desktop/stuff/dev_tests/img/dialtest3.png'))

my_canvas3 = tk.Canvas(frame, width = 1920, height = 1080, background = 'black', highlightthickness=0)
my_canvas3.place(x=1, y=1)


my_canvas3.create_image(960, 540, anchor=CENTER, image=img, tags="image")

        
class Dial():
    count = 200
    upper_limit = 359

    @staticmethod
    def add_Dialcount():
        if Dial.count < Dial.upper_limit :
            Dial.count -= 3
            print(Dial.count)
            CanvasCreate.canvas_Handling()
        else:
            Dial.count = 200
            print(Dial.count)
            CanvasCreate.canvas_Handling()

class CanvasCreate():
        @staticmethod
        def canvas_Handling():
                # Clear Canvas
                my_canvas3.delete("dial")
        # Create RPM Line/bar
                my_canvas3.create_arc(580,160,1340,930, extent=Dial.count, fill='#a15800', tags="dial") 
                my_canvas3.tag_raise("image")
        # Call for the loop to start again
                main_app.after(10,Dial.add_Dialcount)


Dial.add_Dialcount()

main_app.mainloop()
```

When I use this png it works perfectly

[PNG1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54wiq.png)

However when I use this one it's noticeably slower

[PNG2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cjPI.png)

And a screencap of the file sizes, the first PNG's actually a smaller file

[File Sizes PNG2 & PN1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn2z7.png)

I thought maybe a workaround would be to have a transparent canvas and then place the PNG on top of that so I didn't have to raise it every loop, but I don't think you can make a canvas transparent.

PS the dial counter logic is broken but it was a quick and dirty test and doesn't effect this bug, will fix!

Thank you

Comment: there can be many reasons, i think the most one is, if you create new frames and do overlaapping it. try to destroy every widget which you don't need. in your case case it looks like what i say. make a window with three frames and resize it, and then try it with one, you will see the difference

Comment: You know you are trying to run `Dial.add_Dialcount` 100 times a second. I don't think the user will be able to notice if you changed that to 30 times a second.

Comment: maybe you should create `arc` only once and change settings in existing `arc` and runs it every `100ms` to use less CPU?

Comment: Hey guys, I implemented all of the above, it' seems to help a little but it still runs like crap on my pi4, the CPU utilization is around 8% and there's loads of ram overhead when the scripts running so it's not running out of steam. @TheLizzard

Comment: @furas ^^^^^^^^